# Can getPeerCertificates() block indefinitely or for a long time?

Tags: java, ssl, networking, network-programming

Consider the following function:

```
public Certificate[] getCertificates(String ip) throws Exception {
    try (SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket()) {
        SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);
        sslSocket.connect(socketAddress, 10000);
        Certificate[] certificates = sslSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
        return certificates;
    }
}
```

On which terms this code can hang? Basically, I've put a 10 seconds timeout for the connection phase, but is it possible that the code will block for a long time on the `getSession().getPeerCertificates()` part?

Please consider the fact that the ip and port **can be arbitrary** (not even SSL or sometimes not even routable)

Also, this is how I initiate the `sslContext`

```
private SSLContext getSslContext() throws Exception {

    SSLContext sslCtx;
    sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

    sslCtx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {

        private X509Certificate[] accepted;

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
            accepted = xcs;
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return accepted;
        }
    }}, null);

    return sslCtx;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is it possible that the code will block for a long time on the `getSession().getPeerCertificates()`

No.  The `getPeerCertificates()` call on an `SSLSession` returns a copy of the certificates that were presented by the peer in the SSL handshake.  By the call that the `connect` call on the previous line returns, the handshake has completed.